# Replacing an element with HTMLParser in python and using pscyopg2

Tags: python, html-parsing, psycopg2

In my database I have values like this:

```
<p class="description">Text here
    <a href=#>Text here</a>
</p>
```

And I need that whole `<p>` object to replace the same `<p class="description>` in a template file.

```
import sys
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from xml.etree import cElementTree as etree
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras

class LinksParser(HTMLParser):
  def __init__(self):
      HTMLParser.__init__(self)
      self.tb = etree.TreeBuilder()

  def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
      self.tb.start(tag, dict(attributes))

  def handle_endtag(self, tag):
      self.tb.end(tag)

  def handle_data(self, data):
      self.tb.data(data)

  def close(self):
      HTMLParser.close(self)
      return self.tb.close()

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname="**", user="**", password="**", host="/tmp/", port="**")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM landingpagedata;")
row = cur.fetchone()
template = 'template.html'

parser = LinksParser()

parser.feed(open(template).read())
root = parser.close()

#p_class_description
p = root.find(".//p[@class='description']")
p.text = str(row['p_class_description'])
f = open(row['new_html_page'], 'w')
root.write(f)
parser = LinksParser()
```

What I end up with in the file is this:

```
<p class="suggested_readings">&lt;p class="suggested_readings"&gt;Text here &lt;a href=#;"&gt;Text here &lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;
 <a href=#>Text from template</a> and more from template</p>
```

I can't seem to replace the whole element with this element. Or, should I be trying to store an actual element in my database? So helpless here.

Thanks!!!

Comment: In your database is there a `<p>` or `&lt;p&gt;` and the column name is `p_class_description`?

Comment: Yes. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: in `parser.feed()` you open the template but after that you look for a class named `description` that is in the `<p>` inside the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by using [lxml](http://lxml.de/). So now the top uses these:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree
from StringIO import StringIO
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
```

And the implementation looks like this:

```
for row in rows:
  parser = etree.HTMLParser()
  root = etree.parse(template)

  p_class_aboutmaterials = root.find(".//p[@class='about_materials']")
  div_class_aboutmaterials = p_class_aboutmaterials.getparent()
  div_class_aboutmaterials.remove(p_class_aboutmaterials)
  div_class_aboutmaterials.append(etree.XML(row['p_class_aboutmaterials']))
```

I was doomed to have the escaped html because I was converting it to string. Here, I pass it as an XML element.
Getparent() and remove() allow me to replace the content that is already in the template.